# How to generate a Forecast based on last row result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need help to develop the proposed task:

I need to count the current month active employees and then generate a "forecast" for the next six months, the forecast is just the last total active from the current month over the next six months, just changing the date value on the result.

Expected Result:

| Date_Active | Location | Total_Active | Forecast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.04 | 127 | 54 | No |
| 2021.05 | 127 | 54 | Yes |
| 2021.04 | 128 | 32 | No |
| 2021.05 | 128 | 32 | Yes |

So far I just got to count the current month

```
SELECT
CONCAT(YEAR(@Current),'.',MONTH(@Current)) AS Date_Active,
Emp.Location AS Location,
COUNT(Emp.EmpID) AS Total_Active,
CASE WHEN @Current <= @InitialDate THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Forecast
FROM Employees Emp
```

I tried to loop it using while, but without success.

```
WHILE @Current <= @FinalDate
BEGIN
SELECT
CONCAT(YEAR(@Current),'.',MONTH(@Current)) AS Date_Active,
Emp.Location AS Location,
COUNT(Emp.EmpID) AS Total_Active,
CASE WHEN @Current <= @InitialDate THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Forecast
FROM Employees Emp
INNER JOIN 
SET @Current = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Current)
END
```

Assuming @Current is the first day of the given month, @FinalDay is the given month plus six, and @InitialDate is the given date.

It's my first time here, so sorry for any mistakes.

Used fictional data to simplify due to the original being extremely extense.

EDIT:
I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  In addition, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross apply`:

```
select dateadd(month, v,n, t.date_active), location, 
       t.total_active, 1 as is_forecast
from (select t.*,
             max(date_active) over (partition by location) as max_date_active
      from t
     ) t cross apply
     (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)) v(n)
where max_date_active = date_active
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it worked perfectly in my scenario, just one more thing, is there a way to distribute a range of values dynamically?

Comment: @InCeFa . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.